# Incorrect footer position on iOS app build with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

I have a problem with footer position. On iPhone it's too low, it looks like the iphone status bar is not taken into account and query "thinks" there is more space for the whole html.

In a nutshell, footer is 20px too low (status bar is 20px in height).

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar" class="main-tab-bar">
        <ul><li ...><li ...><li ...><li ...></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

on my computer it looks good but when I put it on the phone (as an iphone app) it's misplaced.

Thanks for any tips that may point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a CSS rule to target the page elements and add some margin onto the bottom so the user can scroll to see all of the content:

```
.ui-page {
    margin-bottom : 20px;
}
```

You can also target `data-role="content` elements by using the `ui-content` class.

And yeah this is frustrating. It's amazing that Apple didn't take into account the UI of Safari Mobile which means web developers have to pick-up the slack.

Comment: well, it doesn't change anything :/ here is a screen from simulator, but on device it looks the same http://cl.ly/1o1c3D2f1K2G2S3B0c36 I have tried both options, ui-page and ui-content but tabs are still partially hidden